# Mostrar div según opción que pulso

Tags: javascript, html

Pongo otra pregunta con el problema ya solucionado, pero me falta añadirle animación.

Esto es lo que vendría siendo el menú:

```
 <div class="row men">
   <div id="depilacion" class="col-3 cuadros cuadros-opciones1 center efecto active">
     <h3>DEPILACIÓN <br>LÁSER</h3> 
   </div>
 <div id="lifting" class="col-3 cuadros cuadros-opciones2 efecto center">
     <h3>LIFTING <br> SIN CIRUGÍA</h3>         
 </div>
 <div id="lipoescultura" class="col-3 cuadros cuadros-opciones3 efecto center">
     <h3>LIPOESCULTURA</h3>       
  </div>
  <div id="tattoos" class="col-3 cuadros cuadros-opciones4 efecto center">
     <h3>ELIMINACIÓN <br> TATTOOS</h3>  
  </div>
 </div>
```

Esto es donde mostramos los diferentes `div``

```
 <div id="ContenidoLifting" class="container disNone moduMoradoInterior">
   <h3>Esto el contenido de lifting</h3>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At velit natus itaque a eum. Harum incidunt odio, iure maiores amet quos impedit ipsa id veniam necessitatibus? Enim ab, maxime quam?</p>
 </div>
 <div id="ContenidoLipoescultura" class="container disNone moduMoradoInterior">
   <h3>Esto el contenido de lipoescultura</h3>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At velit natus itaque a eum. Harum incidunt odio, iure maiores amet quos impedit ipsa id veniam necessitatibus? Enim ab, maxime quam?</p>
  </div>
  <div id="ContenidoTattoos" class="container disNone moduMoradoInterior">
    <h3>Esto el contenido de tattoos</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At velit natus itaque a eum. Harum incidunt odio, iure maiores amet quos impedit ipsa id veniam necessitatibus? Enim ab, maxime quam?</p>
  </div>
```

Este es el `JavaScript` que utilizo ahora para mostrar o ocultar:

```
$('div.men > div').on('click',function(){
 $('div.men > div').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#depilacion").on( "click", function() {        
    $("#divMenu > div").not($('#ContenidoDepilacion')).hide(500);        
    $('#ContenidoDepilacion').show(500);
    //$('#ContenidoDepilacion').fadeIn("slow");      
 });
$("#lifting").on( "click", function() {
  $("#divMenu > div").not($('#ContenidoLifting')).hide(500);        
  $('#ContenidoLifting').show(500); 
});
$("#lipoescultura").on( "click", function() {
   $("#divMenu > div").not($('#ContenidoLipoescultura')).hide(500);        
    $('#ContenidoLipoescultura').show(500); 
});
  $("#tattoos").on( "click", function() {
  $("#divMenu > div").not($('#ContenidoTattoos')).hide(500);        
  $('#ContenidoTattoos').show(500); 
});
});
```

Lo que quiero es darle efectos a el `hide` y al `show`. Como por ejemplo : `.fadeIn("slow");`

Comment: Hola, no termina de quedarme claro lo que quieres hacer. ¿A qué te refieres con "según vaya cambiando el div se muestre el que toca"? ¿Podrías poner también tu CSS?

Comment: Voy a poner una respuesta @Kiko_L de la forma que lo acabo de solucionar, aunque no se si es la correcta, pero funciona....

Comment: Acabo de editar mi respuesta. En vez de utilizar el callback de fadeOut lo que hago es llamar a promise() que crear una Promise y espera hasta que termine la animación para lanzar el fadeIn. Échale un vistazo a https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!! @Kiko_L funciona a la perfección

Comment: Ya que estás aprovecha para leer sobre las Promises. Son un concepto muy, muy interesante. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise Y no olvides marcar como correcta la respuesta que consideres oportuna ;)

Comment: Si ahora le doy un vistazo, aun no puedo marcar la respuesta correcta, por que esta en mi respuesta, si quieres publica tu respuesta a parte y te la doy por valida.

Comment: Cierto, no te preocupes. Lo dejamos así ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo solucione así pero no se si es la forma correcta:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#depilacion").on( "click", function() {
        $('#ContenidoDepilacion').show(500,);
        $('#ContenidoLifting').hide(500,);
        $('#ContenidoLipoescultura').hide(500,);
        $('#ContenidoTattoos').hide(500,);
       });
      $("#lifting").on( "click", function() {
        $('#ContenidoDepilacion').hide(500);
        $('#ContenidoLifting').show(500);
        $('#ContenidoLipoescultura').hide(500);
        $('#ContenidoTattoos').hide(500);
      });
      $("#lipoescultura").on( "click", function() {
        $('#ContenidoDepilacion').hide(500);
        $('#ContenidoLifting').hide(500);
        $('#ContenidoLipoescultura').show(500);
        $('#ContenidoTattoos').hide(500);
      });
      $("#tattoos").on( "click", function() {
        $('#ContenidoDepilacion').hide(500);
        $('#ContenidoLifting').hide(500);
        $('#ContenidoLipoescultura').hide(500);
        $('#ContenidoTattoos').show(500);
      });
    });
```

**Edito**

Puedes reducir el código poniendo tus `divs` dentro de otro `div` (`divMenu`) y filtrando con el selector `.not`

```js
   $(document).ready(function () {
$("#depilacion").on("click", function () {
    $("#divMenu div").not($('#ContenidoDepilacion')).fadeOut("slow").promise().done(function () {
        $('#ContenidoDepilacion').fadeIn("slow");
    });
});

$("#lifting").on("click", function () {
    $("#divMenu div").not($('#ContenidoLifting')).fadeOut("slow").promise().done(function () {
        $('#ContenidoLifting').fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
$("#lipoescultura").on("click", function () {
    $("#divMenu div").not($('#ContenidoLipoescultura')).fadeOut("slow").promise().done(function () {
        $('#ContenidoLipoescultura').fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
$("#tattoos").on("click", function () {
    $("#divMenu div").not($('#ContenidoTattoos')).fadeOut("slow").promise().done(function () {
        $('#ContenidoTattoos').fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row men">
  <div id="depilacion" class="col-3 cuadros cuadros-opciones1 center efecto active">
    <h3>DEPILACIÓN <br>LÁSER</h3> 
  </div>
  <div id="lifting" class="col-3 cuadros cuadros-opciones2 efecto center ">
    <h3>LIFTING <br> SIN CIRUGÍA</h3>   
  </div>
  <div id="lipoescultura" class="col-3 cuadros cuadros-opciones3 efecto center">
     <h3>LIPOESCULTURA</h3>   
  </div>
  <div id="tattoos" class="col-3 cuadros cuadros-opciones4 efecto center ">
     <h3>ELIMINACIÓN <br> TATTOOS</h3>  
  </div>
  <div id="divMenu">
    <div id="ContenidoDepilacion" class="">Hola contenido depilación</div>
    <div id="ContenidoLifting" class="">Hola contenido lifting</div>
    <div id="ContenidoLipoescultura" class="">Hola contenido depilación</div>
    <div id="ContenidoTattoos" class="">Hola contenido tattoos</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Con tu permiso te edito la respuesta y añado una versión algo más resumida de tu código.

Comment: Esto está estupendo Kiko_L!!!! funciona perfecto, esa animación de show(500), se puede cambiar por alguna otra?

Comment: Te recomiendo que le eches un vistazo al método animate() de jQuery.

Comment: Gracias! @Kiko_L

Answer (score 0):

He separado el `div`de contenido respecto del `row men` para diferenciarlo, si quieres tu misma estructura solamente deberas ajustar los selectores.
De esta forma se muestra y se desvanece si vuelves a hacer click en los elementos.
Deberias entender el porque de cada cosa y como utilizar atajos con jQuery, te será más facil realizar estas pequeñas cosas.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.mostrar div').hide();
});

$('div.men > div').on('click',function(){
  
  if($(this).attr('id')=='depilacion' & $('.mostrar div#ContenidoDepilacion').css('display') == 'none' ){
   
   $('.mostrar div#ContenidoDepilacion').slideDown("slow"); 
   }else{
    $('.mostrar div#ContenidoDepilacion').hide(); 
   }
  
  if($(this).attr('id')=='lifting'  & $('.mostrar div#ContenidoLifting').css('display') == 'none' ){
    
   $('.mostrar div#ContenidoLifting').fadeIn("slow");
  }else{
    $('.mostrar div#ContenidoLifting').hide();
  }
  if($(this).attr('id')=='lipoescultura'  & $('.mostrar div#ContenidoLipoescultura').css('display') == 'none' ){
   $('.mostrar div#ContenidoLipoescultura').fadeIn("slow");  
  }else{
    $('.mostrar div#ContenidoLipoescultura').hide(); 
  }
  if($(this).attr('id')=='tattoos'  & $('.mostrar div#ContenidoTattoos').css('display') == 'none' ){
   $('.mostrar div#ContenidoTattoos').fadeIn("slow");
  }else{
    $('.mostrar div#ContenidoTattoos').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row men">
  <div id="depilacion" class="col-3 cuadros cuadros-opciones1 center efecto active">
    <h3>DEPILACIÓN <br>LÁSER</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="lifting" class="col-3 cuadros cuadros-opciones2 efecto center ">
    <h3>LIFTING <br> SIN CIRUGÍA</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="lipoescultura" class="col-3 cuadros cuadros-opciones3 efecto center">
    <h3>LIPOESCULTURA</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="tattoos" class="col-3 cuadros cuadros-opciones4 efecto center ">
    <h3>ELIMINACIÓN <br> TATTOOS</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mostrar">
  <div id="ContenidoDepilacion" class="">Hola contenido depilación</div>
  <div id="ContenidoLifting" class="">Hola contenido lifting</div>
  <div id="ContenidoLipoescultura" class="">Hola contenido depilación</div>
  <div id="ContenidoTattoos" class="">Hola contenido tattoos</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola de nuevo @ntzz, probe tu solución, pero me muestra me va mostrando todos pero sin ocultar los demás, se puede poner además animación??

Comment: @Miguel Creo que esto es lo que pides, he añadido un par de efectos diferentes, puedes utilizar `animate` y realizar la animación que tu desees. EJ: https://jqueryui.com/toggle/

Comment: Que lo añado aquí al final? $("#depilacion").on( "click", function() {        
              $("#divMenu div").not($('#ContenidoDepilacion')).hide(500);        
              $('#ContenidoDepilacion').show(500);        
           });

@ntzz

Comment: Eso es otra forma diferente, no tiene nada que ver.
Tampoco entiendo a lo que te refieres, si quieres editar tu pregunta con el codigo nuevo que estas usando y así intentamos ayudarte de la mejor manera posible.

Comment: Hola de nuevo @ntzz acabo de actualizar la pregunta para poder enseñarte donde quiero mostrar la animación. Gracias